# How to validate request parameter if it is not a bean in spring MVC?

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-mvc, spring-validator

Below is a POST end point in my spring MVC REST service. I want to use spring validation frame work to make sure that list I receive is not empty. How do I do it? Do I have to provide wrapper bean to around `listOfLongs`?

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/some/path", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public Foo bar(@Valid @NotEmpty @RequestBody List<Long> listOfLongs) {

     /*   if (listOfLongs.size() == 0) {
            throw new InvalidRequestException();
        }
     */

        // do some useful work
    }
```

What should be the Request Body?

```
1) [123,456,789]
2) { listOfLongs : [123,456,789]}
```

Answer (score 4):

Providing a wrapper bean is a good practice.

```
class LongList {

 @NotEmpty
 private List<Long> listOfLongs;

 // Setters and Getters ...

}
```

Then, the Request Body should be  `{ listOfLongs : [123,456,789]}`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/some/path", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Foo bar(@Valid @RequestBody LongList listOfLongs) {   

    // do some useful work
}
```

Comment: How to validate, if the param is only a String? And don't want to wrap.

Comment: Why is this good practice? Its only generating boilerplate code