# Spring MVC - @Valid on list of beans in REST service

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, bean-validation

In a Spring MVC REST service (json), I have a controller method like this one :

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = { "/doesntmatter" })
@ResponseBody
public List<...> myMethod(@Valid @RequestBody List<MyBean> request, BindingResult bindingResult) {
```

Where the MyBean class has bean validation annotations.

The validations don't seem to take place in this case, although it works well for other controllers.

I don't want to encapsulate the list in a dto this that would change the json input.

Why is there no validations for a list of beans ? What are the alternatives ?

---

Comment: you can use this https://stackoverflow.com/a/36313615/3110023

Answer (score 57, accepted):

`@Valid` is a JSR-303 annotation and JSR-303 applies to validation on JavaBeans.  A `java.util.List` is not a JavaBean (according to the [official description](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnair.html) of a JavaBean), hence it cannot be validated directly using a JSR-303 compliant validator.  This is supported by two observations.

> Section **3.1.3** of the [JSR-303 Specification](https://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/#d0e991) says that:
>
> *In addition to supporting instance validation, validation of graphs of object is also supported. The result of a graph validation is returned as a unified set of constraint violations. Consider the situation where **bean X contains a field of type Y**. By **annotating field Y with the @Valid annotation**, the Validator **will validate Y (and its properties) when X is validated**. The exact type Z of the value contained in the field declared of type Y (subclass, implementation) is determined at runtime. The constraint definitions of Z are used. This ensures proper polymorphic behavior for associations marked @Valid.*
>
> ***Collection-valued, array-valued and** generally **Iterable fields and properties may also be decorated with the @Valid annotation**. This causes the contents of the iterator to be validated. Any object implementing java.lang.Iterable is supported.*

I have marked the important pieces of information in bold.  This section implies that in order for a collection type to be validated, it must be encapsulated inside a bean (implied by `Consider the situation where bean X contains a field of type Y`); and further that collections cannot be validated directly (implied by `Collection-valued, array-valued and generally Iterable fields and properties may also be decorated`, with emphasis on **fields and properties**).

> Actual JSR-303 implementations

I have [a sample application](https://github.com/manish-in-java/stackoverflow-questions/tree/master/17207766) that tests collection validation with both Hibernate Validator and Apache Beans Validator.  If you run tests on this sample as `mvn clean test -Phibernate` (with Hibernate Validator) and `mvn clean test -Papache` (for Beans Validator), both refuse to validate collections directly, which seems to be in line with the specification.  Since Hibernate Validator is the reference implementation for JSR-303, this sample is further proof that collections need to be encapsulated in a bean in order to be validated.

---

With that cleared, I would say that there is also a design problem in trying to pass a collection to a controller method directly in the way shown in the question.  Even if validations were to work on the collections directly, the controller method will be unable to work with alternate data representations such as custom XML, SOAP, ATOM, EDI, Google Protocol Buffers etc. which do not map directly to collections.  For supporting those representations, the controller must accept and return object instances.  That would require encapsulating the collection inside an object instance any way.  It would therefore be highly advisable to wrap the `List` inside another object as other answers have suggested.

Answer (score 13):

The only way i could find to do this is to wrap the list, *this also means that the JSON input would have to change*.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = { "/doesntmatter" })
@ResponseBody
public List<...> myMethod(@Valid @RequestBody List<MyBean> request, BindingResult bindingResult) {
```

becomes:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = { "/doesntmatter" })
@ResponseBody
public List<...> myMethod(@Valid @RequestBody MyBeanList request, BindingResult bindingResult) {
```

and we also need:

```
import javax.validation.Valid;
import java.util.List;

public class MyBeanList {

    @Valid
    List<MyBean> list;

    //getters and setters....
}
```

This looks like it could also be possible with a custom validatior for lists but i have not got that far yet.

> The @Valid annotation is part of the standard JSR-303 Bean Validation API, and is not a Spring-specific construct.
>   Spring MVC will validate a @Valid object after binding so-long as an appropriate Validator has been configured.

Reference : http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html

Answer (score 5):

Try direct validation. Something like this:

```
@Autowired
Validator validator;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = { "/doesntmatter" })
@ResponseBody
public Object myMethod(@RequestBody List<Object> request, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    for (int i = 0; i < request.size(); i++) {
        Object o = request.get(i);
        BeanPropertyBindingResult errors = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(o, String.format("o[%d]", i));
        validator.validate(o, errors);
        if (errors.hasErrors())
            bindingResult.addAllErrors(errors);
    }
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors())
        ...
```

Comment: Yes, but it's a lot of lines that would be avoided with an annotation.

Answer (score 4):

There is a elegant way to wrapper your request in a custom `java.util.List` which acts as both `List` and `JavaBean`. [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36313615/2576076)

Answer (score 4):

Using com.google.common.collect.ForwardingList

```
public class ValidList<T> extends ForwardingList<T> {

  private List<@Valid T> list;

  public ValidList() {
    this(new ArrayList<>());
  }

  public ValidList(List<@Valid T> list) {
    this.list = list;
  }

  @Override
  protected List<T> delegate() {
    return list;
  }

  /** Exposed for the {@link javax.validation.Validator} to access the list path */
  public List<T> getList() {
    return list;
  }
}
```

So no need for the wrapper

you may use

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = { "/doesntmatter" })
@ResponseBody
public List<...> myMethod(@Valid @RequestBody ValidList<MyBean> request, BindingResult bindingResult) {
```

By using wrapper your JSON needs to be changed to

```
{
  "list": []
}
```

with this implementation you can use original JSON

```
[]
```

Answer (score 4):

Given Spring-Boot + Jackson for JSON serialization + `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation` (must be included manually for spring boot >= 2.3.0)

**Using built-ins**

- add `@Validated` to your controller
- use `@Valid @NotNull @RequestBody List<@Valid Pojo> pojoList` in your controller method signature

This will throw a `javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException` error on invalid beans though, which is mapped to `500 Internal Error` by default. Hence, ensure you have a `ControllerAdvice` for this as well !

**Using a wrapper**

A list wrapper is nice (that is, a class with a single field of type `List<E>`), but from the responses above you will have to change the JSON as well (`{"list": []}` vs `[]`), which is not nice...

Solution:

- in the wrapper, use `@JsonValue` annotation on the wrapped list field
- add a constructor taking a list as argument, and annotate it with `@JsonCreator`
- in your controller method, use `@Valid @RequestBody ListWrapper<Pojo> tokenBodies`

This works, is elegant, and doesn't require anything more. Moreover, it will throw the usual `org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException` on invalid beans.

---

**Wrapper Example (java)**:

(For a full example in **Kotlin**, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/64060909)

```java
public class ValidList<E> {
    @JsonValue
    @Valid
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, message = "array body must contain at least one item.")
    private List<E> values;

    @JsonCreator
    public ValidList(E... items) {
        this.values = Arrays.asList(items);
    }

    public List<E> getValues() {
        return values;
    }

    public void setValues(List<E> values) {
        this.values = values;
    }
}
```

```java
public class SomePojo {
    @Min(value = 1)
    int id;

    @Size(min = 2, max = 32)
    String token;

    // getters and setters
}
```

```java
@RestController
public class SomeController {

    @PostMapping("/pojos")
    public ValidList<SomePojo> test(@Valid @RequestBody ValidList<SomePojo> pojos) {
        return pojos;
    }
}
```

Submit ok:

```sh
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:8080/pojos -d '[{"id": 11, "token": "something"}]'
```

```json
[{"token" : "something", "id" : 11}]
```

Submit empty body:

```sh
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:8080/ns -d '[]'
```

```json
{
   "timestamp" : "2020-09-25T09:55:05.462+00:00",
   "error" : "Bad Request",
   "message" : "Validation failed for object='validList'. Error count: 1",
   "exception" : "org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException",
   "path" : "/pojos",
   "status" : 400,
   "trace": "org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException: Validation failed for argument [0] in public com.example.demo.ValidList<com.example.demo.SomePojo> com.example.demo.SomeController.test(com.example.demo.ValidList<com.example.demo.SomePojo>): [Field error in object 'validList' on field 'values': rejected value [[]]; codes [Size.validList.values,Size.values,Size. [...]"
}
```

Submit invalid items:

```sh
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:8080/ns -d '[{"id": -11, "token": ""}]'
```

```json
{
   "timestamp" : "2020-09-25T09:53:56.226+00:00",
   "error" : "Bad Request",
   "message" : "Validation failed for object='validList'. Error count: 2",
   "exception" : "org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException",
   "path" : "/pojos",
   "status" : 400,
   "trace": "org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException: Validation failed for argument [0] in public com.example.demo.ValidList<com.example.demo.SomePojo> com.example.demo.SomeController.test(com.example.demo.ValidList<com.example.demo.SomePojo>) with 2 errors: [Field error in object 'validList' on field 'values[0].id': rejected value [-11]; co [...]"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Implement your own validator with org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean as a member and call that validator for each item.

```
public class CheckOutValidator implements Validator {


    private Validator validator;

   @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) { 
    List request = (List) target;
    Iterator it = request.iterator()   
    while(it.hasNext()) {
    MyBean b = it.next();
    validator.validate(b, errors);

     }

     }

//setters and getters

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to write a wrapper for each List you have, you can use a generic wrapper:

```
public class ListWrapper<E> {

    private List<E> list;

    public ListWrapper() {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public ListWrapper(List<E> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Valid
    public List<E> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List<E> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public boolean add(E e) {
        return list.add(e);
    }

    public void clear() {
        list.clear();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your best option is to wrap the list - [How to validate request parameter if it is not a bean in spring MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16908689/how-to-validate-request-parameter-if-it-is-not-a-bean-in-spring-mvc)

There is no way atm to say that the *@Valid* applies to the elements of the collection.

Comment: Is there any way to wrap the list in a way that that would not change the json input?

Answer (score -4):

```
@Valid @RequestBody List<MyBean> request
```

works for me so long as you submitting valid json:-

```
[
    {
        "property1": "value1",
        "property2": "value2"
      },
    {
        "property1": "value3",
        "property2": "value4"
        }
]
```

Comment: This indeed works if you submit valid JSON, but the question was about how to trigger the validation with `@Valid` if the JSON is not valid...