# Cascaded bean validation 2.0 not working with nested object inside Map

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, bean-validation

**Although, this question has been answered I'm interested why `@Validated` is needed for a working cascaded validation of `Map<String, @Valid Employee>`.**

**Update 2**: For some deeper understanding I've found those posts ([One](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57696133/4065938),[Two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54394177/4065938) and [Three](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38962827/4065938)), which explains, that `@Validated` is neeeded to activate method level validation. With the help of this, collections can be validated, due they are no JavaBeans which are validated instead (JSR 303).

---

**Solution**: I've updated my code snippets and my repository with working code examples. All I have to do is to annotate my controller with  `@Validated` and add some getters in `Employee`. `MethodValidationPostProcessor` is not necessary at all.

**Update**: I've updated my question and forked Spring Boot Rest example to add a minimal Rest API to demonstrate:

[Github Repo](https://github.com/Theiaz/map-with-bean-validation-2/tree/master/rest). 
The example values are inside README.md!

---

I've got an Spring Boot 2 API to store some employees. I can pass either one `Employee`  or either a `Map<String, Employee>`.

```
@Validated //this is the solution to activate map validation
@RestController
class EmployeeController {

  @PostMapping("/employees")
  List<Employee> newEmployee(@RequestBody @Valid Employee newEmployee) {
     ...
  }

  @PostMapping("/employees/bulk")
  List<Employee> newEmployee(@RequestBody Map<String, @Valid Employee> 
  newEmployees) {
     ...
  }
}
```

Employee exists of some inner static classes which also needs to be validated:

```
public class Employee {

    @NotBlank
    public final String name;
    @Valid
    public final EmployeeRole role;

    @JsonCreator
    public Employee(@JsonProperty("name") String name,
        @JsonProperty("role") EmployeeRole role) {

        this.name = name;
        this.role = role;
    }

    // getters

    public static class EmployeeRole {

        @NotBlank
        public String rolename;

        @Min(0)
        public int rating;

        @JsonCreator
        public EmployeeRole(@JsonProperty("rolename") String rolename,
            @JsonProperty("rating") int rating) {

            this.rolename = rolename;
            this.rating = rating;
        }

        // getters
    }
}
```

For now, validation for single requests are working but not for my bulk requests. As far as i know this should be possible with Bean validation 2.0.

Do you know what I've did wrong? Do i need to write a custom validator?

Comment: Try remove @NotNull from CalculationRequestContext.

Comment: I don't why this should help, maybe some explanation? However, it did not help at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make it working you have to do following:

> Add `MethodValidationPostProcessor` bean to configuration

```
@Bean
public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
    return new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
}
```

> Add `@Validated` to your `EmployeeController`

```
@Validated
@RestController
public class EmployeeController {}'
```

> Add `@Valid` to `Map` or to `Employee`

```
public List<Employee> newEmployee(@RequestBody @Valid Map<String, Employee> newEmployees) {}   
public List<Employee> newEmployee(@RequestBody Map<String, @Valid Employee> newEmployees) {}
```

That's all. This is entire `EmployeeController`:

```
@Validated
@RestController
public class EmployeeController {

    @PostMapping("/employees")
    public List<Employee> newEmployee(@RequestBody @Valid Employee newEmployee) {
        return Collections.singletonList(newEmployee);
    }

    @PostMapping("/employees/bulk")
    public List<Employee> newEmployee(@RequestBody @Valid Map<String, Employee> newEmployees) {
        return new ArrayList<>(newEmployees.values());
    }
}
```

And SpringBoot configuration file

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
        return new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
    }

}
```

**Hope it help you.**

Comment: @Theiaz right. I have updated the answer. I have checked - it works to me.

Comment: This is working! Can you tell me why i do need this instead of working Bean Validation 2 out of the box?

Comment: I can’t. I do not know all Spring internals. I suppose this is not the one way, should be another one.

Comment: Okay, however thanks for the answer. Maybe somebody else could answer this. 

Fyi: `MethodValidationPostProcessor` is not necessary at all.

Answer (score 3):

There are two kinds of validation in spring system.

- A: The spring boot controller methods parameter validation, only works for the http post request body data in controller with `@Valid` or `@Validated` aside
- B: The method level validation, works for any method parameters and return values with `@Validated` on class and `@Valid` aside values to be validated

We can see that A is more narrow while B is a more common one. I'd like to answer the question on two aspects.

### 1 Answers are in the code

As describe in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28150405/validation-of-a-list-of-objects-in-spring/54394177#54394177), the `more detail` part, A and B triggers method enhancement via aop by calling different method in 
`org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl`, which leads to the difference.

- A call `validate` method in `ValidatorImpl` via `RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor`
- B call call `validateParameters` method in `ValidatorImpl` via `MethodValidationInterceptor`

They are different methods with different functions, so lead to different results. You can find the answer by reading the two methods.

### 2 Answers are in the specification

The [JSR-303](https://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/) defines functions of the methods we discussed above.

`validate` method is explained in the [validation method](https://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/#validationapi-validatorapi-validationmethods) part, and the implementation must obey the logic defined in [validation routine](https://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/#constraintdeclarationvalidationprocess-validationroutine), in which it states that it will execute all the constraint validation for all reachable fields of the object, this is why element of `List` object (or other collection instance) cannot be validated via this method - the elements of the collection are not fields of the collection instance.

But `validateParameters`, JSR-303 actually doesn't treat it as main topic and put it in `Appendix C. Proposal for method-level validation`. It provides some description:

```
The constraints declarations evaluated are the constraints hosted on the parameters of the method or constructor. If @Valid is placed on a parameter, constraints declared on the object itself are considered.

validateReturnedValue evaluates the constraints hosted on the method itself. If @Valid is placed on the method, the constraints declared on the object itself are considered.

public @NotNull String saveItem(@Valid @NotNull Item item, @Max(23) BigDecimal price)

In the previous example,

- item is validated against @NotNull and all the constraints it hosts
- price is validated against @Max(23)
- the result of saveItem is validated against @NotNull
```

and exclaim that `Bean Validation providers are free to implement this proposal as a specific extension`. As far as I know, the `Hibernate Validation` project implements this method, makes constraints works on the object itself, and element of collection object.

### 3 Some complain

I don't know why the spring framework guys call `validate` in `RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor`, makes lots of related questions appeare in stackoverflow. Maybe it's just because http post body data usually is a form data, and can be represented by a java bean naturally. If it's me, I'll call the `validateParametes` in `RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor` for easy use.