# javax.validation 2.0.1 List<Object> not working in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, javax.validation

I am new the spring boot developement. I am trying to validate the post request by passing List from @RequestBody. Below is control class

```
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/webapi/device")
@Validated
public class DeviceController extends AuthControllerImpl{

    @Autowired
    private DeviceServices deviceServices;


    //Test Postman request 01
    @PostMapping(path = "/udateDevices", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,  produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> updateDeviceToDB( @RequestBody List<@Valid Device> device, @RequestParam("token") String token, Errors errors)    {
        if (errors.hasErrors()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<Object>(new ErrorResponse(errors), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        if(isValidToken(token) != null){
            DeviceControllerResponse response = deviceServices.updateDeviceToDB(device);
            if (!response.isSuccess()) {
                return new ResponseEntity<Object>(response, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            }
            return ResponseEntity.ok(response); 
        }else {
            return new ResponseEntity<Object>("Token has been expired/not valid.", HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }

    }
}
```

Below is my entity class.

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document(collection = "rpDevices")
public class Device {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @NotEmpty(message = "device udid should not be empty")
    private String udid;

    @NotEmpty(message = "deviceModel should not be empty")
    private String deviceModel;

    @NotEmpty(message = "device location should not be empty")
    private String location;

    @NotEmpty(message = "device port should not be empty")
    private String port;

    private String url;

    private String lastUpdate;
    private String imsi;
    private String msisdn;

    private String aliasName;

    public Device() {
        super();
    }

    public Device(String id, String udid, String deviceModel, String location, String port, String url,
            String lastUpdate, String imsi, String msisdn, String aliasName) { 
        this.id = id;
        this.udid = udid;
        this.deviceModel = deviceModel;
        this.location = location;
        this.port = port;
        this.url = url;
        this.lastUpdate = lastUpdate;
        this.imsi = imsi;
        this.msisdn = msisdn;
        this.aliasName = aliasName;
    }
    //Getter and setters 

}
```

It never validates the entity and giving the below error.

```
    {
    "timestamp": 1591497348682,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "javax.validation.UnexpectedTypeException",
    "message": "HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty' validating type 'java.lang.String'. Check configuration for 'updateDeviceToDB.device[0].port'",
    "path": "/xxxx/webapi/device/udateDevices"
}
```

Can some one help how to validate the List directly from request boday.
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-validate-list-controller I tried this but not helps.

here are the pom dependencies

```
        <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.21.RELEASE</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>


        <!-- Adding spring boot cap -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.restdocs</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-restdocs-mockmvc</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Adding spring boot security,ldap -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- starter-data-mongodb MongoRepository -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- javax.mail -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- some other stuff related to testing -- >

</dependencies>
```

Comment: Have you ever explicitly declared `validation-api` or `hibernate-validator` in your jar dependencies? If declared, please remove it. There is a complicated relationship between validation api and validator. Spring Boot handles that well.

Comment: I added the javax.validation 2.0.1 , But i remove the this i can't List<@Valid Device>  declare this and showing error not available.

Comment: Please post your jar dependencies configuration file in your question.

Comment: added the pom dependencies

Comment: Use `NotBlank` instead `NotEmpty`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**validation-api** is the specification, **hibernate-validator** is the implementation, simply speaking.

**spring-boot-starter-web** will automatically import **hibernate-validator**, then **hibernate-validator** will automatically import **validation-api**.

With your jar dependencies configuration, there are two version of `validation-api`. One is `1.1.0` imported by `hibernate-validator 5.3.6` (from spring-boot-starter-web), and the other is `2.0.1` imported by your explicit declaration. `validation-api 2.0.1` will be used with `hibernate-validator 5.3.6`, which is incompatible. Causing no validator could be found error.

When you remove `validation-api 2.0.1`, `1.1.0` version will be used. But `javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty` not introduced with `validation-api 1.1.0`, so you will get another error.

Several ways to solve this problem:

1. remove `validation-api 2.0.1`, use `org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty` instead of `javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty`.
2. remove `validation-api 2.0.1`, upgrade spring boot version to 2.x, it will use hibernate-validator 6.x and validation-api 2.x.
3. keep your explicit `validation-api 2.0.1` declaration. Then add another `hibernate-validator 6.0.14` declaration. This case should be fully tested, cause there are maybe some Spring support issues.

Comment: 1st option : i can't use the this option since validate 1.1.0 didn't support List<@Valid Device> option .(Direct list validation is not support)
2nd Option: This would take long time to fix the compatible issues with MongoRepository and other
3rd Option : This is working fine but sure about  Spring support issues you mentioned. 
Thanks @HowieChinh

Comment: @Sri If you could change your request data structure, with 1st option, you may want to proceed like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36313615/5374508. If you couldn't, try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54394177/5374508 with a little extra exception handling work.

Answer (score 4):

I was having the similar issue, if you are using spring boot version (2.3.0) and above then `validation-api` wont work.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Just add the above dependency in `pom.xml`.
See release notes: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.3-Release-Notes#validation-starter-no-longer-included-in-web-starters

Comment: Thank you, you save me a lot

Answer (score 0):

The `Errors` parameter should follow the validated parameter:

```
public ResponseEntity<Object> updateDeviceToDB( @RequestBody List<@Valid Device> device, Errors errors, @RequestParam("token") String token)
```

This is required in order to support multiple validated parameters in a single method.

Answer (score 0):

```
public ResponseEntity<Object> updateDeviceToDB(@Valid @RequestBody List<Device> device, @RequestParam("token") String token, Errors errors)
```

It is common to validate a model after binding user input to it. Spring 3 provides support for declarative validation with JSR-303. This support is enabled automatically if a JSR-303 provider, such as Hibernate Validator, is present on your classpath. When enabled, you can trigger validation simply by annotating a Controller method parameter with the @Valid annotation:

Visit This Link : https://spring.io/blog/2009/11/17/spring-3-type-conversion-and-validation/

Comment: What do you mean by "This Required valid for Entity Class"

Comment: Yah i don't understand ether "This Required valid for Entity Class". Could you explain more what it is?

Comment: Check Above Edited Answer.