# Unable to perform Bean validation on elements of an Array in Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation, javabeans

I have a Spring Boot app where I need to perform validation of an object.

Object which has to be validated:

```
public class MyObject {
   @NotNull
   @Size(min=5)
   @ApiModelProperty(value = "first name", required=true)
   private String firstName;

   //getters and setters for firstName
}
```

Now in my controller I have two methods-

```
public ResponseEntity<RespObject> getSingleResp(@Valid @RequestBody MyObject myObj) {
//Bean validation works I get a 400 if validation fails, only if it is valid then execution enters this method
}

public ResponseEntity<RespObject[]> getMultiResp(@Valid @RequestBody MyObject[] myObjs) {
//Bean validation does not happen here and starts execution of this method
}
```

I have also tried adding `@NotNull` `@NotEmpty` in between `@Valid @RequestBody` and `MyObject[] myObjs` to see if that validation happens, but it doesn't seem to work.

Am I missing something silly here or does Bean validation doesn't work for the individual elements of an array? If it does not work then is there a work-around to solve this?

I found a similar question for List, but the solution over there doesn't seem to work for me. [Validation of a list of objects in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28150405/validation-of-a-list-of-objects-in-spring)

Comment: Did you try replacing `MyObject[]` with `List<MyObject>`

Comment: can you paste your entire controller class? or check if you have `@Validated` annotation  on the class level in your controller