# Custom Validation of lists in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, validation

I have a simple object:

```
public class Student {
    private int id;

    @Max(18)
    @Min(3)
    private int age;
}
```

My rest controller receives a list of students. How can I validate the min and max age and that the IDs in the list are not duplicated?

I tried writing my own validator but it's not working.

```
public class StudentsValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidStudents, List<Student>> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(ValidStudents constraintAnnotation) {
        ConstraintValidator.super.initialize(constraintAnnotation);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(List<Student> students, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
        if (students == null || students.isEmpty())
            return true;
    
        if (students.stream().anyMatch(students -> students.getAge() < 3 || students.getAge() > 18))
            return false;
    
        return students.stream().map(Student::getID).distinct().count() == students.size();
    }
}
```

My annotation:

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = StudentsValidator.class)
public @interface ValidStudents {
    String message() default "Invalid list of students";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

And then in my controller I use it like this:

```
public void putStudents(@RequestBody @ValidStudents List<@Valid Student> students)
```

I'm assuming I wouldn't need to run a @Valid before Student if my @ValidStudents was working but I'm trying both and neither works. What am I missing?

Also, is there anyway I can throw a bad request after the validation fails besides writing my custom exception handler?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add `@Validated` into your controller class level to enable AOP validation. Refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28150405/validation-of-a-list-of-objects-in-spring)

Answer (score 0):

This worked. I ended up removing the @Valid and leaving the @ValidStudents. My intellij wasn't picking up the changes so I thought it wasn't working.

And also as @phuongnq1995 said, make sure you have the @Validated at class level in your controller.