# List of dtos is not validated

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data

In put request of my REST API I want to send list of DTOs. Each of these DTOs have field *value*, that I would like to validate. The validation works if I have custom DTO to hold list of my DTOs. Like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RestController {

  private final RestService restService;

  @PutMapping
  public void update(@RequestBody @Valid ListOfDtos listOfDtos) {
    return restService.update(listOfDtos.getDtos());
  }
}

@Data
public class ListOfDtos {

  @Valid
  private List<@Valid DTO> dtos;
}

@Data
public class DTO {

  @Pattern(regexp = "[^~]+") //do not allow any string containing '~'
  private String value;
```

But I would love to simplify my code, by not having ListOfDtos object. I would expect it to work by just modifying RestController.update method like this:

```
  @PutMapping
  public void update(@RequestBody List<@Valid DTO> dtos) {
    return restService.update(dtos);
  }
```

But after this change my DTOs are not validated.
`@RequestBody @Valid List<@Valid DTO> dtos`
Can You explain me please why does this not work, and also how to fix it without adding the encapsulating ListOfDtos class?

Answer (score 1):

The only elegant way to solve this problem was to use Lombok as proposed by @laffuste in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28150405/validation-of-a-list-of-objects-in-spring)

```
@Data
public class ValidList<E> implements List<E> {
    @Valid
    @Delegate
    private List<E> list = new ArrayList<>();
}

@PutMapping
public void update(@RequestBody @Valid ValidList<DTO> dtos){
    return restService.update(dtos);
}
```

Exaplanation of why does this not work is in the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54394177/12794090).