Validate Kafka message when batch processing
I am batch processing messages using spring kafka listener and I want them to be validated before processing. Here's how I have configured my kafka listener
@KafkaListener(id = "listener.id",
      topics = "kafka.events",
      idIsGroup = true,
      batch = "true",
      concurrency = "1")
  public void onMessage(@Valid @Payload ConsumerRecords<String, KafkaEvent> consumerRecords) {
    ...
  }

And my event message looks as below - fields are annotated with required constraints against which they need to be validated:
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class KafkaEvent {
    @NotNull 
    @Size(min = 1, max = 64) 
    private String eventId;
    
    @NotNull @PositiveOrZero 
    @Digits(integer = 20, fraction = 6)   
    private  BigDecimal amount;

    ....
}

As per the documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/kafka/receiving-messages/validation.html, I have also configured a validator:
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class Config implements KafkaListenerConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator;
    
    @Override
    public void configureKafkaListeners(KafkaListenerEndpointRegistrar registrar) {
      registrar.setValidator(this.validator);
    }
}

But fields are not getting validated if I follow the above approach. So, I had to change my approach, create an error de-serializer to handle the deserialization failures and a custom validator which I am setting in de-serializer to validate the messages. As I understand from the documentation, we do need an error de-serializer to handle deserialization failures but do we really need a custom validator to validate the messages in batch? Shouldn't messages in the batch be validated by spring itself after deserialization, if we have correctly placed the @Valid @Payload annotations.
Approach 2:
application.yaml
consumer:
      value-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      ...
      properties:
        spring.deserializer.value.delegate.class: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
        spring.deserializer.validator.class: com.shinky.myservice.validator.CustomValidator
    

Validator
import jakarta.validation.Validation;
import jakarta.validation.Validator;
import org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter;

public class CustomValidator extends SpringValidatorAdapter {

  public CustomValidator() {
    super(validator());
  }

  public static Validator validator() {
    return Validation.byDefaultProvider()
        .configure()
        .buildValidatorFactory().getValidator();
  }
}

I wanted to understand, if I have missed something on implementation because of which validation is not working using @Payload and @Valid annotations or if this is intentional for any valid reason?

According to the documentation, are you using Spring Boot with the (validation) starter? https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-validation

yes, using v3.2.0. I also have rest APIs in code, there input JSON is getting validated.

You are using ConsumerRecords which doesn't have any validation annotations, only the records it wraps. The @Valid works only with object that themselves have validation related annotations. Using it on the plain object will work as also stated in the documentation.

Thanks Deinum! Although I do need ConsumerRecords but I have tried passing-in List<KafkaEvent>, it still doesn't work.

Are you solve this problem?

This is actually a slight variation of Validation of a list of objects in Spring.
To make it work add @Validated on the class containing the @KafkaListener.
In my case I did not need the ConsumerRecords, so I tested this solution only with List<MyDto>.
For a detailed explanation see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54394177/12794090

Actually your solution with CustomValidator helped me.
public class DeserializerValidator extends SpringValidatorAdapter {

    public DeserializerValidator() {
        super(Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator());
    }
}

it validated in
@KafkaListener(id = "businessListener", topics = "${app.topic}", batch = "true", idIsGroup = false)
void listen(List<ConsumerRecord<String, Business>> business) {
    // not validated

}

