# Spring boot, how to use @Valid with List<T>

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, bean-validation

I am trying to put validation to a Spring Boot project. So I put `@NotNull` annotation to Entity fields. In controller I check it like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public DataResponse add(@RequestBody @Valid Status status, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return new DataResponse(false, bindingResult.toString());
    }

    statusService.add(status);

    return  new DataResponse(true, "");
}
```

This works. But when I make it with input `List<Status> statuses`, it doesn't work.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/bulk", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public List<DataResponse> bulkAdd(@RequestBody @Valid List<Status> statuses, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    // some code here
}
```

Basically, what I want is to apply validation check like in the add method to each Status object in the requestbody list. So, the sender will now which objects have fault and which has not.

How can I do this in a simple, fast way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My immediate suggestion is to wrap the List in another POJO bean. And use that as the request body parameter.

In your example.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/bulk", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public List<DataResponse> bulkAdd(@RequestBody @Valid StatusList statusList, BindingResult bindingResult) {
// some code here
}
```

and StatusList.java will be

```
@Valid
private List<Status> statuses;
//Getter //Setter //Constructors
```

I did not try it though.

**Update:**
The accepted answer [in this SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17207766/spring-mvc-valid-on-list-of-beans-in-rest-service) gives a good explanation why bean validation are not supported on Lists.

Answer (score 1):

with using Kotlin and Spring Boot Validator

```
@RestController
@Validated
class ProductController {
    @PostMapping("/bulk")
    fun bulkAdd(
        @Valid
        @RequestBody statuses: List<Status>,
    ): ResponseEntity<DataResponse>> {...}
}

data class Status(
    @field:NotNull
    val status: String
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just mark controller with [@Validated](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/annotation/Validated.html) annotation.

It will throw `ConstraintViolationException`, so probably you will want to map it to `400: BAD_REQUEST`:

```
import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation;
import javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;

@ControllerAdvice(annotations = Validated.class)
public class ValidatedExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handle(ConstraintViolationException exception) {

        List<String> errors = exception.getConstraintViolations()
                                       .stream()
                                       .map(this::toString)
                                       .collect(Collectors.toList());

        return new ResponseEntity<>(new ErrorResponseBody(exception.getLocalizedMessage(), errors),
                                    HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    private String toString(ConstraintViolation<?> violation) {
        return Formatter.format("{} {}: {}",
                                violation.getRootBeanClass().getName(),
                                violation.getPropertyPath(),
                                violation.getMessage());
    }

    public static class ErrorResponseBody {
        private String message;
        private List<String> errors;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just adding @Validated annotation does not work with a List<T>

Answer (score 0):

```
@RestController
@Validated
@RequestMapping("/products")
    public class ProductController {
        @PostMapping
        @Validated(MyGroup.class)
        public ResponseEntity<List<Product>> createProducts(
            @RequestBody List<@Valid Product> products
        ) throws Exception {
            ....
        }
}
```