# Validate patch request body -Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Is there any way to validate the patch request body in spring boot?

```
Ex:
[
  {"op": "replace", "path": "/id", "value": "foo"},
   {"op": "replace", "path": "/id2", "value": "foo2"}
]
```

if any user sends the request with "op"(field) as "xx" and "path"(field) as "se". Is there any way to validate it and throw 400 (Bad Request), without changing the contract?

Comment: This isn't really clear to me. Did you write your own REST controller? Do you want to verify that `"op"` is a specific value (eg `"replace"` but not `"xx"`)? What do you mean by "without changing the contract"? Is your request body structure the contract?

Comment: You can go through this article: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-validators

Comment: @g00glen00b yes. I meant the request body.
In my question, I'm referring "op" field not the "op" value("replace")

Comment: Maybe you can provide (at least) the method signature ? you probably need to add a @ Valid before your @ RequestBody

Comment: @Gremi64  @ Valid is not working as expected when the body is a List. Patch request body is a list.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17207766/spring-mvc-valid-on-list-of-beans-in-rest-service or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28150405/validation-of-a-list-of-objects-in-spring or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39348234/spring-boot-how-to-use-valid-with-listt

Comment: Maybe you can do a foreach on your list and apply  javax validator on each element ?

Comment: Yeap Gremi64  :(  . I think that is the solution. I thought there is a better way to do this. But I can't find any other solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried many ways to solve this. But finally had to go with this solution.

My patch request signature:

```
public void patch(@RequestBody List<PatchOperation> operations)
```

I created a simple function to verify valid patch keys are present in the request.

```
void validatePatchOperation(PatchOperation patchOperation) {
    if (patchOperation.getOp() == null) {
        throw new BadRequestException();
    }
    if (patchOperation.getPath() == null) {
        throw new BadRequestException();
    }
    if (patchOperation.getValue() == null) {
        throw new BadRequestException();
    }
}
```

And used this inside a for-each