# @Valid annotation is not working for list of json request

Tags: java, validation, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I tried to validate the list of json request but it is not working.

Json request

```
[
  {
    "name": "AA",
    "location": "Newyork"
  },

  {
    "name": "BB",
    "location": "Delhi"
  }
]
```

Here is my controller class

Controller class

```
@RestController
@Validated
@RequestMapping("/v1.0")

public class Controller {
        public ResponseEntity<List<Response>> ConversionResponse(    @RequestBody List<@Valid Request> req) throws Throwable {
       List<Response> response = new ArrayList<Response>();
            for (request request : req) {
    
                response = services.conversion(request, response);
    
            }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
```

Here @Valid annotation doesnot validate the list

POJO class

```
public class Request{  
    
@NotNull
private String name;

@NotNull(message="Location should not be null")
private String location;
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}
public void setLocation(String location) {
    this.location = location;
}
        
    }
```

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. After Spring-boot 2.3.0, you need to manually add the
   `spring-boot-starter-validation` to your project.
2. Use `@RequestBody List<@Valid Req> reqs` instead of `@RequestBody @Valid List<Req> reqs`.
3. Add `@Validated` on the Controller Class.
4. It will throw `ConstraintViolationException`, so you may want to map it into `400 Bad Request`.

sources: [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-validate-list-controller), [Question 39348234](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39348234/spring-boot-how-to-use-valid-with-listt)

Comment: I have added spring-boot-starter-validation in my pom.xml. Still it is not working

Comment: Oh, ok. I just saw that you're trying to validate a List. So change the @Valid position to: conversionResponse(@RequestBody List<(@Valid Request> req)

Comment: The change in position of @Valid also not working.

Comment: Try adding @Validated into your controller class (among with RestController, RequestMapping).

Comment: I have added like this: in controller 
RestController
Validated
RequestMapping("/v1.0")
public ResponseEntity<List<CalculatedFormulaModel>> functionConversionResponse(
    RequestBody List<Valid CalculatedFormulaModel> sapBoFunction) throws Throwable { 
still it is not working. I removed all the @ here for comment purpose

Comment: weird.. add your spring dependencies in yout post. i'll try to setup a minimal project here

Comment: I have added the annotations in the class.

Comment: what's your spring parent version?

Comment: Spring parent version is 2.5.7

Comment: https://github.com/guilhermestella/stackoverflow-71402889
Check this out. It's the same Spring version and it's working.