# Jhipster : How to generate code for list of Entity / Plural Entity

Tags: jhipster

Let's say I have an entity **Book**
I want Jhipster to generate a **Books** Entity something like

```
class Books{
  List<Book> books;
}
```

And Generate corresponding rest controllers like

```
Books saveAllBooks(Books books)
Books updateAllBooks(Books books)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to create a `Books` entity if it contains only a list of `Book` entities, you could just add manually the list methods to generated REST controller`BookResource.java` as you don't need any additional repository.

But if `Books` has other fields that you want to persist in database, you could generate 2 entities with one-to-many relationship. I wouldn't recommend using plural as it could probably conflict with other generated code.

```
entity Book{
   title String required
}

entity BookBatch{
    name String required
}

// RELATIONSHIPS:
relationship ManyToOne {
    Book to BookBatch
}
```

Comment: The main reason I want to create `Books` entity is that `@Valid` annotation does not validate `Lists` as explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17207766/spring-mvc-valid-on-list-of-beans-in-rest-service.
Can you suggest a workaround?

Comment: Yes don't use an entity, use a DTO.