# Spring Boot - Bean Validation 2.0 Validation of a list of objects

Tags: java, spring-boot, bean-validation

I am using springBoot 2 and I am trying to validate the objects in a List via:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/bets",
    produces = {"application/json"},
    consumes = {"application/json"},
    method = RequestMethod.POST
)
void postBets(@RequestBody List<@Valid Bet> bets);
```

and Bet class has @NotNull annotations on certain attributes.

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

public class Bet extends BetMessage {

@NotNull
private String categoryName;

@NotNull
private String marketName = null;

@NotNull
private OffsetDateTime startTime = null;

@NotNull
private String betName = null;
```

I have also added the spring-boot-starter-validation artifact to my build file but still no validation is happening.

As a workaround I have implemented the popular answer in the question below (ValidList class) and validation is working as expected; however I think that I am missing something obvious and the solution is now part of the validation library.

[Validation of a list of objects in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28150405/validation-of-a-list-of-objects-in-spring)

Comment: Did you try changing `List<@Valid Bet> bets` into `@Valid List<Bet> bets`?

Comment: @JakubPogorzelski yes - tried both ```@Valid List<Bet> bets``` and ```@Valid List<@Valid Bet> bets``` but neither have worked

Comment: you may check Chapter 2 of  the documentation https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/pdf/hibernate_validator_reference.pdf

Answer (score -1):

You may want to write a wrapper which contains your list of Bet because then your wrapper will conform to JavaBean specs and the validations can be applied.

Below Answer might help in this case.

[@Valid on list of beans in REST service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17207766/spring-mvc-valid-on-list-of-beans-in-rest-service)