# Validating a Map<String, Object> map using spring validator

Tags: java, spring, validation

I have tried implementing validation for a list of objects, using bean encapsulation as stated here

[Spring MVC - @Valid on list of beans in REST service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17207766/spring-mvc-valid-on-list-of-beans-in-rest-service)

I want to know if it is possible to validate a custom map, (Map<String, Object>), using a spring validator.