# Why can't I use Valid parameter along with RequestParam in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, bean-validation

Example:

```
public String getStudentResult(@RequestParam(value = "regNo", required = true) String regNo, ModelMap model){
```

How can I use @valid for the regNo parameter here?

Comment: No you cannot. `@Valid` only works for objects not primitive structures like a `String` or `Integer` for example. If you want to validate you will have to do it  yourself.

Comment: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-6380

Answer (score 15):

Late answer. I encounter this problem recently and find a solution. You can do it as follows,
Firstly register a bean of `MethodValidationPostProcessor`:

```
@Bean
public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
    return new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
}
```

and then add the `@Validated` to the type level of your controller:

```
@RestController
@Validated
public class FooController {
    @RequestMapping("/email")
    public Map<String, Object> validate(@Email(message="请输入合法的email地址") @RequestParam String email){
    Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    result.put("email", email);
    return result;
    }
}
```

And if user requested with a invalid email address, the `ConstraintViolationException` will be thrown. And you can catch it with:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class AmazonExceptionHandler {

@ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
@ResponseBody
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public String handleValidationException(ConstraintViolationException e){
    for(ConstraintViolation<?> s:e.getConstraintViolations()){
        return s.getInvalidValue()+": "+s.getMessage();
    }
    return "请求参数不合法";
}
```

}

You can check out my demo [here](https://github.com/amit-gshe/spring-demos/tree/master/spring-validation-demo)

Comment: The MethodValidationPostProcessor bean was the missing piece of the puzzle for me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

@Valid can be used to validate beans. I have'nt seen it used on single string parameters. Also it requires a validator to be configured.

> The @Valid annotation is part of the standard JSR-303 Bean Validation API, and is not a Spring-specific construct.
>   Spring MVC will validate a @Valid object after binding so-long as an appropriate Validator has been configured.

Reference : http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html

Comment: Thanks for answering. May I know how can I validate a single String parameter for my Spring MVC project to validate in Sever side.

Comment: 2) My another question is, can I use both @ModelAttribute and @RequestParam(value = "regNo", required = true) together?

Answer (score 2):

one way to do it is to write a Wrapper Bean like the following :

```
 public class RegWrapperBean{

        @NotNull
        String regNo ; 

        public String getRegNo(){
             return regNo ;
        }

        public void setRegNo(String str){
             this.regNo=str;
        }

}
```

and your handler method will be like the following :

```
  @RequestMapping(value="/getStudentResult", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String getStudentResult(@Valid @ModelAttribute RegWrapperBean bean,
            BindingResult validationResult, Model model) {
    }
```

and please refer to these answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6205027/957654) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16909362/957654) .

Hope that Helps .